# Converting a decimal time number (such as 23.33154) to seconds in Python?

Tags: python, math, time, logic, data-conversion

Im trying to convert a decimal time number such as 23.456, 0.5555, 1.9999 etc. to seconds (as a whole number).

I have made a function that converts the decimal time to hours and minutes.
For example, converting to hours:

```
def decimal_to_hours(t)
    return math.floor(t)
```

And then for decimal time to minutes:

```
def decimal_to_mins(t)
    if t < 1:
        return math.floor(t * 60)

    if t % 1 == 0:
        return 0

    elif t > 1:
        return math.floor((t - math.floor(t)) * 60)
```

So my problem is I don't know how I would convert the fraction to seconds. Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: Also assume that the decimal can't exceed 23.99999999

Comment: What does a "decimal time" represent? What is its data type?

Comment: decimal time is a float, like for example, t = 23.99431 should return 39 seconds

Comment: This is a math/logic problem, not a Python one.

Comment: Ok, any input then? I added "math and "logic" as tags. Sorry if my post etiquette is bad, this is my first time using this site.

Comment: What unit is the "decimal time number"?

Answer (score 3):

Just convert to seconds and do the original operation: floored modulo.

```
from math import floor

time_hours = 23.99431
time_minutes = time_hours * 60
time_seconds = time_minutes * 60

hours_part   = floor(time_hours)
minutes_part = floor(time_minutes % 60)
seconds_part = floor(time_seconds % 60)

print("{h}:{m}:{s}".format(h=hours_part, m=minutes_part, s=seconds_part))
#>>> 23:59:39
```

Comment: maybe `"{h}:{m:02d}:{s:02d}"` ?

Comment: why is "hours_part = floor(time_hours % 60)" instead of "floor(time_hours)" (if the original value was 25.99431)?

Comment: @TimRichardson Erm, I meant `% 24`. Even so it doesn't make much sense if I'm not printing days. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
def convert_decimal_to_time(decimal):
    values_in_seconds = [('days', 60*60*24), ('hours', 60*60), ('minutes', 60), ('seconds', 1)]
    output_dict = {}
    num_seconds = int(decimal * 3600)
    for unit, worth in values_in_seconds:
        output_dict[unit] = num_seconds // worth
        num_seconds = num_seconds % worth
    return output_dict

convert_decimal_to_time(23.99431)
# {'minutes': 59, 'hours': 23, 'days': 0, 'seconds': 39}
convert_decimal_to_time(2.75)
# {'minutes': 45, 'seconds': 0, 'hours': 2, 'days': 0}
convert_decimal_to_time(252.5)
# {'minutes': 30, 'seconds': 0, 'hours': 12, 'days': 10}
```